# facebook custom button xcode 8 (swift 3) , action doesn't work

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I try even simple code from facebook developer page ,
fb button redirect me on app confirm (page say : already confirmed)-  not to the facebook login page.
If i (safari) log in on FB , nothing change ...

This is the code :

```
    func loginButtonClicked() {
    var login = FBSDKLoginManager()
 //   login.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], fromViewController: self, handler:{(result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       login.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], fromViewController: self, handler:{(result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult? , error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error {
            print("Process error")
        }
        else if result.isCancelled() {
            print("Cancelled")
        }
        else {
            print("Logged in")
        }            
    })
}
```

**Error log :**

> /Users/nikola/Documents/Nikola_Lukic/xcode_projekti_8_beta/gitHub_repo_Swift_projects/UI
>   basic
>   template/UI_controls/UI_nidza_template/UI_nidza_template/facebookLoginForm.swift:72:97:
>   Cannot convert value of type '(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?,
>   NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type
>   'FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler!'

Comment: It is a good practice to add some good tag related to the post, so that it many people can reach to your question, and you may the answer very soon.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and it's similar to an error with Restkit where the error is `cannot convert value of type (RKObjectRequestOperation!, RKMappingResult!) -> Void to expected argument type (RKObjectRequestOperation?, RKMappingResult?) -> Void!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
       func loginButtonClicked() {
        var login = FBSDKLoginManager()
        login.logIn(withReadPermissions:["public_profile"], fromViewController: self, handler:{ response ,error in
        if error {
          print("Process error")
        }
        else if result.isCancelled() {
          print("Cancelled")
        }
        else {
          print("Logged in")
        }            
     })}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the type.

```
handler:{(result , error)-> Void in
```

It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Change error type from NSError to Error.